# How to wire capacitor start ac motor

Tags: ac, induction-motor

I have a motor with a blue, yellow, black, and orangish wire coming out of it and I'm trying to figure out how that should be connected to power based on the wiring diagram on the side of this motor.

Could you point me towards a resource that would help me understand this wiring diagram? Thank you

**Edit**: I took the motor apart a bit more and have some additional information.

- Light blue is connected to the centrifugal switch that turns off the starter winding
- Oranges goes though the thermal protection then turns red and goes into the windings
- Black turns into blue that goes into the windings
- Yellow goes into the windings

Based on this information I decided to connect blue, yellow, and my neutral together and then orange, black, and hot together. This got the motor turning, but it sounded a little funny so I wanted to see if someone else came to a different conclusion from me. I also am attaching  another photo.

[image: Motor label and wires]
[image: Inside the motor]

Comment: Judging from the diagram, it seems like there are some type of terminal posts, possibly numbered 1, 2, 4 and 5. Do you see those anywhere? I am pretty sure blue and yellow are the phase windings and red and black are the start cap windings, but not 100% sure. Are you able to measure the DC resistance from wire to wire with an Ohmeter?

Comment: @mkeity you are right about the terminal posts. There is a black wire inside connected to 4 which goes to the capacitor. The windings seem to have a blue, yellow, and red coming from them.

Comment: Yellow and black have almost no resistance between each other. The rest are not connected.

Comment: Hmm. So there is high resistance between yellow and blue? That is not what I expected. Unfortunately, I am not an expert on these kinds of things. If there are terminal posts, though, I think the diagram is telling you which wires to connect to which terminal posts. All you would have to do, assuming the motor itself is correctly connected up, is connect AC to posts 1 and 4 to make the motor spin. Did you try searching for the model number online?

Comment: @mkeith, I have searched around and have not been able to find info about a motor with the same setup. I have provided more information in the description. Let me know if that helps or raises more questions. Thank you.

Comment: I think your conclusion is probably correct. Yellow and black must be the main winding. Orange and blue are the start winding. The reason the start winding has high DC resistance is the series start capacitor. I suggest you swap orange and blue and see if it makes the motor spin in the opposite direction. The purpose of the this is just to confirm that everything behaves as expected.